# Nested Intersect

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table for sold items contains customer_id and item_name. 
I need to create a new table to get 
customers with intersected items contains
customer_a_id , customer_b_id , intersected_items_count.

I wrote a PL/SQL procedure with cursor and nested for-loop 
to perform this operation, but what if I have a million customers
this means 1m * 1m loops

my question is: is there any sql method for nested intersect (intersect all rows with all rows in a table)

my table like this:

```
customer_id   item
1              Meat 
1              Rice 
2              Meat
2              Soups 
3              Pasta
```

requested output:

```
customer_a_id customer_b_id intersected_items
1              2             1
1              3             0
2              1             1
2              3             0
3              1             0
3              2             0
```

Comment: Why do you want customer 1 intersected with customer 2 ***and*** customer 2 intersected with customer 1? You appear to have twice as many results as necessary to be complete.  *(Combinations vs Permutations)*

Comment: you are right dear , but since I used pl cursor and for-loops , this caused the unneeded duplicate 1 with 2 and then 2 with 1.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A self-join of the customer table will produce the desired result set

```
    SELECT c1.id        customer_a_id 
         , c2.id        customer_b_id
         , COUNT(*)     intersected_items
      FROM customer c1
      JOIN customer c2
        ON (
                 c1.id <> c2.id
             AND c1.item = c2.item
           )
  GROUP BY c1.id
         , c2.id
         ;
```

There is the obvious optimization of `c1.id < c2.id`.

**Supplement**

As @JuanCarlosOropeza notes, the above solution does not contain id pairs with non-intersecting item sets. This is by design, given the cited table size of 10^6.

However, for the sake of completeness and acknowledging that the OP has not asked to skip these pairings, the following query produces the non-intersecting items as well:

```
    SELECT x.customer_a_id
         , x.customer_b_id
         , COALESCE(matches.intersected_items, 0)   intersected_items
      FROM (
                SELECT c_all_1.id        customer_a_id 
                     , c_all_2.id        customer_b_id
                  FROM customer c_all_1
            CROSS JOIN customer c_all_2
                 WHERE c_all_1.id < c_all_2.id
              GROUP BY c_all_1.id
                     , c_all_2.id
           ) x
 LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT c1.id        customer_a_id 
                     , c2.id        customer_b_id
                     , COUNT(*)     intersected_items
                  FROM customer c1
                  JOIN customer c2
                    ON (
                             c1.id < c2.id
                         AND c1.item = c2.item
                       )
              GROUP BY c1.id
                     , c2.id
           ) matches
        ON (
                matches.customer_a_id = x.customer_a_id
            AND matches.customer_b_id = x.customer_b_id
           )
  ORDER BY intersected_items desc
         , customer_a_id 
         , customer_b_id 
         ;
```

Comment: You want a `LEFT JOIN` to get the 0 intersect

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Given the table size and assuming that the 0 intersect information has no significance,  the inner join might do.

Comment: You cant assume 0 intersect has no significance when OP has 0 on his desire output.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza In principle you are right. However, I am confident that the OP does not intend to handle a result set with a trillion records ...

Comment: I would go as far as saying "If a result is in the OP but not returned by the answer, the answer is incomplete".  If it's a relevant aspect of the OP, ask in the comments instead of making an unstated *(in the answer)* assumption?

Comment: Thanks dear @collapsar , really self-join solve my question and no need for PL what is recommended for performance tuning ? creating index on what ?

Comment: @MatBailie In principle I agree with you as I do with _JuanCarlosOropeza. Any asumptions, as naturallly as they may come, should be stated in the answer, I've complemented it accordingly.

Comment: @MhdH_Nahhas An index on `item` would definitely help.

Comment: Really don't understand your additional complicated query. When the only thing you need is a `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I don't think it is as easy as replacing the inner with a left join. Tuples for id pairings that have disjoint item sets will be generated by a left join, but with of the ids missing. Moreover, in grouping by ids, all tuples such with a single id are folded into one record.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this using `cross join` and `left join`s:

```
select c1.customer_id, c2.customer_id, count(t2.item) as num_intersected_items
from (select distinct customer_id from t) c1 cross join
     (select distinct customer_id from t) c2 left join
     t t1
     on t1.customer_id = c1.customer_id left join
     t t2
     on t2.customer_id = c2.customer_id and t2.item = t1.item and
where c1.customer_id <> c2.customer_id
group by c1.customer_id, c2.customer_id;
```

This version gives you control of the customer ids -- they could come from a different table and include customers with no items.

The results are equivalent to a `left join`, if all the items are coming from the same table:

```
select t1.customer_id, t2.customer_id, count(t2.item) as num_intersected_items
from t t1 left join
     t t2
     on t1.item = t2.item 
where t1.customer_id <> t2.customer_id
group by c1.customer_id, c2.customer_id;
```

Comment: I think you miss the `GROUP BY`

Comment: Is there any difference on performance if you split the join condition to the `WHERE` or is just matter of preference? I would add the  `t1.customer_id <> t2.customer_id;` to the `ON` clausule. My logic is `WHERE` have to filter after make a match but if you add the condition `ON` then there isnt a match. But of course my logic doesn't have any real fact behind so I rather ask.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza . . . No difference in performance, just semantics.  This is an outer join, so to actually filter out rows from t he first table, the condition needs to be a `where` condition.